# Sort by using drop down and variable in MySQL statement (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, mysqli

I am trying to sort my results by using a drop down menu. I want to get a value from the drop down and enter it into a MySQL statement by assigning it to a variable. I have tried a few things with no success. Any ideas? Thank you.Before I could pull the data from the table and it displayed correctly. It's just the sorting issue.

```
<form name="order" method="post">
                          <select name='order'>
<option value='ORDER BY product_name ASC'>A-Z
<option value='ORDER BY product_name DSC'>Z-A
<input type="submit" value="Submit"  />
                        </select>
                        </form> 

       <div id="Products">
          <p>
            Products:
          </p><?php
              $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db_tc");
          // Check connection

         $order=$_POST['order'];

              if (mysqli_connect_errno())
              {
                echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
              }
              $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tbl_products ORDER BY $order");



              while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
              {
                echo "<div id='item'>";
                echo "<div id= 'pic'><img class='pic' src='". $row['product_img'] . "'/></div>";
                echo "<div id= 'itemname'><h1> <a href=\"product.php?id=". $row['product_id'] ."\">" . $row['product_name'] . "</h1></a></div>";
                echo "<div id= 'price'> <h2>Price:</h2><br>£" . $row['product_price'] . "</div>";
                echo "<div id= 'signed'> <h2>Signed:</h2><br>" . $row['product_signed'] . "</div>";
                echo "<div id= 'type'> <h2>Type:</h2><br>" . $row['product_type'] . "</div>";

                echo "</div>";
              }
              echo "</table>";

              mysqli_close($con);
              ?>
        </div>
```

Comment: You have a big security issue with sql injection here.

Comment: You have value='ORDER BY product_name ASC' and again using the keyword "ORDER BY" in the SQL. Was that by mistake?

Comment: Well spotted! It's partially fixed it. Yes I have essentially cut down everything to the basics to get this working. My main version has SQL protection.

Comment: Ah the order by fixed it! Thank you. My mistake!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well the value you are sending with the $_POST field is "ORDER BY name ASC" and you try to add it to a sql statement which already contains "ORDER BY" clause which might be the problem for you. And I guess it's "DESC" not "DSC"

Have you considered, what would have happened if someone added a single quote to the value of the select field and post that? You should always escape the values you receive from the user. Better if you use prepared statements too.